# Processing(.org) for geospatial visualization?

Tags: visualisation

Does anyone know if [Processing](http://www.processing.org/) is being used for geospatial visualization? I can't find much out there, but this is impressive: http://benfry.com/zipdecode/

Here's one I just found: http://fathom.info/projects/countyhealth.html

Comment: This suggests it has been tried: http://forum.processing.org/topic/macosx-calling-64-bit-code-through-swig-jni-bindings-for-gis-application

Comment: hahaha.That was me asking. Nobody helped. Nevertheless, after some self inflicted pain (I hate Java) I got it working perfectly fine. Ask away, although by now you probably already figured it out :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some examples:

- bus arrivals in Portland:
  http://www.flickr.com/photos/ewedistrict/2549055956/
- rental bike usage in London:
  http://vimeo.com/19486470
- an IRC network:
  http://vimeo.com/16897839

I've seen a lot of others like these--do you mean to ask about a more specific kind of visualization?

Comment: these are great! do you know of any code out there? i'm most interested in events along a street network, like the bus arrivals.

Comment: I've read Ben Fry's book, but haven't had a chance to do much personally.  Just in searching, these might be good places to start: 1) London Tube Map (with code): http://www.tom-carden.co.uk/p5/tube_map_travel_times/applet/ 2) Processing Tutorials: http://processing.org/learning/ 3) Processing Wiki: http://wiki.processing.org/w/Main_Page

Answer (score 5):

UnfoldingMaps is a library for map display, map interaction and geovisualisation for Processing.

Some examples here: http://unfoldingmaps.org/

Comment: those example visualizations are beautiful!

Answer (score 2):

[giCentre](http://www.soi.city.ac.uk/organisation/is/research/giCentre/) @ CITY University London has created [geoMap](http://www.gicentre.org/geomap/). It's quite young project but there is some [documentation](http://www.gicentre.org/geomap/reference/) available and [code samples](https://code.google.com/p/gicentre-geomap/wiki/Examples).

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I had a small question. I actually would like to build an application which is very similar to( http://tillnagel.com/2011/06/tilemill-for-processing/ ) but as a map and not on “Multi touch Table Top”.

The functionality I need is

Plot different cities of California with different radius, the different radius will represent number of times a person has visited a city.

When a person clicks on a city e.g LA it should show plot a polyline to different cities which are nearby. As shown in the link above.

I was wondering if you could help me on this, if you could give me a right direction to start with will be real great.

Thanks

Mehul

Comment: try posting a new question!